# Is it possible to use ASP.NET application caching in web API?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5

For example, in a ASP.NET page you would do something like

`Cache.Add({...})` and access it via `Cache["key"]`.  In this context, Cache is the `System.Web.Caching.Cache` object.

Is there anyway to do this type of ASP.NET application level caching in web API controllers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are web hosting, why not?

```
var context = HttpContext.Current;

if (context != null)
{
    if (context.Cache["g"] == null)
    {
        context.Cache["g"] = 9.81;
    }
}
```

But you are adding a dependency on ASP.NET by doing so. Even though ASP.NET Web API has ASP.NET in the name, the Web API is host-agnostic. That is, ASP.NET/IIS is not the only hosting option; the Web API can be self-hosted as well. Something for you to consider before going down that route.

Answer (score 11):

Take a look at the [MemoryCache class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.aspx).  From its MSDN documentation:

> The MemoryCache class is similar to the ASP.NET Cache class. The
>   MemoryCache class has many properties and methods for accessing the
>   cache that will be familiar to you if you have used the ASP.NET Cache
>   class. The main differences between the Cache and MemoryCache classes
>   are that the MemoryCache class has been changed to make it usable by
>   .NET Framework applications that are not ASP.NET applications.

You can create a new instance of a MemoryCache yourself, or you can use the default AppDomain-wide instance via the `MemoryCache.Default` static property.

*Edit: You'll need to add a reference to System.Runtime.Caching.dll if you wish to use this type.*

Comment: Can you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914870/danger-of-using-fire-and-forget-in-asp-net-mvc/16915126#16915126

Comment: Not sure why this doesn't have more upvotes (and should be the accepted answer). This behaves much like the ASP.NET cache and still allows for portability without being tied to ASP.NET/IIS

Answer (score 1):

You need to type

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache
```

to access the instance. There is no `Cache` property declared at the `Controller` level, like on a `Page`.

Note that the context that hosts the API will need to support caching.

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to Output caching in ASP.NET Web API. Take a look at this project,

https://github.com/filipw/AspNetWebApi-OutputCache