# Danger of Using Fire and Forget in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am using Fire and Forget in ASP.NET MVC application means that I am spawning a long running CPU or IO intensive background thread which does not depend upon user need. This works great but I am fearing that during the process of application domain/process recycling  time my background thread is guarantee to run to completion or it might stop at the middle. If there is any danger then how to avoid this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct answer(Windows Service or [WebBackground](https://github.com/NuGet/WebBackgrounder)),

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you need a guarantee that the process runs until completion, then running it under the webserver is indeed the wrong place. You should consider placing your long-running task in a Service and to communicate to it from the webserver via some sort of IPC (WCF springs to mind).

Answer (score 2):

I think ASP.NET MVC is not the right choice here. You should look at using Workflow Foundation. A workflow can be triggered by making a WCF call.